# passing data from port to xml()

Tags: apache-flex

AM reading data from port in the form of bytes.my data will be like

```
<book name="xxx">
  <title>First</title>
</book>
```

and i want this data to pass in

```
var xml:XML=new XML();
```

to show in the grid in run time of my desktop application.When i pass the data

```
var socket:Socket = event.target as Socket;
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
socket.readBytes(bytes);
var xml:XML=new XML(bytes);
```

its not working. but when i pass

```
var xml:XML=new XML("<book name="xxx"><title>First</title></book>");
```

is works fine.

please guide me to get solve.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to be using the socket for XML data I suggest you have a look at the [`XMLSocket`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html).

An [`XML`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html) object does not expect to receive bytes in its constructor, which you are currently giving it. That's the reason why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

The XML class uses the global XML() converter function to read the contents of the data.  This will not understand a byteArray, so you will need to convert your byteArray to something more readable.  You could try (untested):

```
var xml:XML=new XML(bytes.readUTFBytes(bytes.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load your XML file by using an URLRequest. With this request you can load your data and with a eventlistener you can use the loaded data to parse it into XML.

Here's an example.

```
protected function getXMLfile():void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("yourURL");
                    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
                    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
                    loader.load(req);       
                }
                catch(err:Error){
                    Alert.show(err.message);
                }
            }

private function loaderCompleteHandler(evt:Event):void {                
                try {
                    var niveau:uint = 0;                    
                    var xmlFile:XML = new XML(evt.target.data);                     

                } catch (err:Error) {
                    Alert.show("Could not parse the XML file.");
                }
            }
```

This should work fine. For more information you can contact me.
Hope this will help you.